# Getting a specific tag and combining if multiple same tags are found together

Tags: regex, matlab, char

I want to keep the words with the  tag `NA`. If more than one such words come together, I want to combine them into a one word.

Example:

```
%if i have
a='[The/D, handle/NA, of/NS, the/NaAq, hair/NA, brush/NA, is/NaAZ broken/A]'
% the output I want:
output={'handle', 'hair brush'}
```

I tried with searching for `/NA` but the problem is there are false positives which are `the`, `is`.

Currently my code is:

```
g=split(a(2:end-1));
b= strfind(g,'/NA');
g(~cellfun(@isempty, b))
```

Any ideas how to proceed? Any one-line regular expression will be very helpful if possible.

Comment: Just to make sure: do you want `output={'handle', 'hair brush'}` or `output={'handle', 'hair', 'brush'}`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the first one. If there are multiple such words together, I want to combine them

Comment: The only approach I can think of with regex is extracting all the substrings with `\w+/NA\b(,\s*\w+/NA\b)*` and then remove `/NA,?` from all the matches found.

Comment: Thanks. `/NA,?` solves the issue of false positives. But I am unable to use the first regex you mentioned in Matlab. It correctly matches in http://www.regextester.com/

Comment: It does not work because of a `\b`, it is not supported. So, you can only do it like `\w+/NA(,\s*\w+/NA)*` or `\w+/NA(,\s*\w+/NA)*(?!\w)`

Comment: That's helpful.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a nice NLP problem. Maybe this gets you started:

```
a='[The/D, handle/NA, of/NS, the/NaAq, hair/NA, brush/NA, is/NaAZ broken/A]';
output={'handle', 'hair brush'};

expr = '(\S+/NA, )+';                       % look for words followed by '/NA, '
match = regexp(a,expr,'match');
output = strtrim(strrep(match,'/NA,',''))   % strrep: get rid of tag - strtrim: get rid of tailing blank
```

Note that this approach will fail if the last word is tagged with /NA. You can catch that case independently though.